# jump table numbers

Tags: tables

I have a list of tables: 1,2,3,5,6,8.

I would like the number of table 5,6 and 8 to be 5, 6 and 8, instead of 4,5 and 6 (the latex automatic choice). This is because I am referring in the text to tables 4 and 7, which I do not have yet.

Is there a way to do this?

thank you

Comment: You should never refer to tables by number if you refer to the table using `\ref{table-about-foobar}`  then it will use whatever number  the table has and if you add more tables the number will change.

Comment: Thank you David. That's exactly my problem. I want specific portions of text to be linked to a specific table even if the table changes numbers. For instance, the text could be "The main results are reported in Table \ref{mainResults}". In. this way, that part of the text about the main results is linked to the main results table.

Comment: That is exactly what `\ref` is designed to do, so what is the problem? (you can force the numbers (just `\setcounter{table}{100}` ) but it is absolutely not necessary for the problem as you have described it.

Comment: perfect! \setcounter solves the problem! thank you!

Comment: No really it does not. `\ref` is designed to solve the issue that you described, `\setcounter` is the wrong thing to do here almost certainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your objectives correctly, you can achieve them (a) by issuing the instruction

```
\stepcounter{table}
```

before the fourth `table` environment and (b) by issuing yet another

```
\stepcounter{table}
```

instruction before the sixth and last `table` environment. That way, the `table` counter will skip over the numbers 4 and 7, and the six LaTeX-generated `table` environments will be numbered 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, and 8, respectively.

Comment: thank you! that solves the problem!